# What is the right approach to use AdSense with responsive web design?

Tags: google-adsense, responsive-webdesign

Recently I was studying responsive design a lot and designed couple of sites. But I was wondering how would I use Google AdSense (which is pixel based) ads on my responsive design?

Very typical example is suppose I have a `728x90` ads on header. Or if I do a mobile first approach I would need different versions of ad sizes for different view posts but Google doesn't allow more than three ad unit per page (as far as I know).

So, Question: **What is the right approach/best practice of using Google AdSense on a responsive site design?**

Comment: I don't think there is any approach. Adsense simply does not integrate with responsive design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like Google now has "Responsive Ad Units" to fit in with responsive designs.

You can read more about this at: https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/3213689

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you could use it the horizontal leader boards in a responsive design.

The two ways i could think of incorporating it would be to:

1. use **sky scrapers** and **mpu** ads that would sit in a side bar and then come in to be part of the responsive design.
2. detect that the viewing device is a tablet or phone and run mobile ads accordingly (keeping the rest of the site responsive as is.)

Comment: one thing i was thinking about is pushing the adsense code after the page load via javascript. So, i know what size of ad i should inset. what do you think about that?

Comment: Technically it would work, but my only concern is that adsense might think your messing around with their ad tag as i suppose the same could be done to produce more impressions, and they could ban you